# Voltage divider for symmetrical DC power

Tags: voltage, divider

[image]

Let's imagine there is a symmetrical DC power supply +10V and -10V and two resistors, R1=10k and R2=100k. What is the voltage in point A? What is the correct formula for this kind of calculation?

Comment: This is not a site where we do your homework for you. Please edit your question to include the work you've done and exactly where you're stuck on this problem.

Comment: A voltmeter has two leads.  If one of then is connected to point A, where is the other one connected?  Without this information, your question has no meaning.  There are three places to connect it, and each gives a unique result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage between two points is called a potential difference. In most cases, the potential difference between two points is well defined. When one speaks of the voltage at a single point, one usually means the potential difference between that point, and some point that is arbitrarily defined as 0 volts. We call this point ground. (Unfortunately, the word "ground" also has other meanings). We add a ground symbol to a schematic to identify the node that we have arbitrarily chosen to be the O V reference. If a schematic lacks a ground symbol, a reference to "the voltage" at a single point is likely not well defined.

However, in your schematic, there is a node that is labelled +10V, and this node can serve a similar purpose in providing a reference.

The total resistance of the circuit is 110 k\$\Omega\$. The total voltage across those resistors is 20 V. Thus the current through them is 20/11k. When that current passes through the 10 k resistor, a voltage of 10k*20/110k = 1.818 V will devop across it. Since one end of the 10 k resistor is at 10 V, node A will be at 10-1.818=8.182 V.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for a voltage divider is

$$
E_n = E_{total}\times \frac{R_n}{R_{total}}
$$

Where:

\$R_n\$ is the resistor or series of resistors you want to find the voltage across.

\$E_n\$ is the voltage across \$R_n\$.

\$R_{total}\$ is the total resistance in the divider.

\$E_{total}\$ is the voltage across the entire divider.

This can be applied to a divider with any number of resistors, but two resistors is what you typically see.

Example: In the following circuit we want to find the voltage across R2, this will be our \$R_n\$. \$R_{total}\$ will be 3.3k + 1.2k = 4.5k and \$E_{total}\$ will be the total supply voltage, 15 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftqbty.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We get:
$$
E_n = 15~V\times \frac{1.2k}{4.5k} = 4~V
$$

This finds the voltage dropped across the resistor, if you want to reference that to another node in the circuit, such as the common connection of two voltage sources, you would then have to add any voltages between \$R_n\$ and that point, in this case we would add the voltage across R2 to -5 V and the voltage at \$R_{n1}\$ with respect to *Reference* would be -1 V. It would be a good idea to label the voltages with + and -, then following the circuit starting at \$R_{n1}\$ and ending at *Reference* you get (+4 V) + (-5 V) = -1 V.